# php if foreach statement works, but else message not displaying

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach

I'm getting an array of data from my model, and am using a php foreach statement to display it in a view. I'm adding another layer of logic to show only certain bookmark_ids.

The data is displaying fine; but for some reason the "else" message (tied to the first if clause) isn't showing if no data is returned. I need to figure out how to get that message to display.

```
<?php 

     if ($bookmark): 
     foreach($bookmark as $b): ?>               

     <?php if ($b->bookmark_id != 0) { ?>               

     <li><?php echo $bk->user_id; ?> <?php echo $bk->bookmark_name; ?></li>

     <?php } ?>


     <?php
      endforeach;
        else:
          print "Your bookmark list is empty.";
    endif;

?>
```

Comment: If-else condition is wrong.. Plus there's nothing called endforeach in php

Comment: Your `$bookmark` might be not empty, that's why the `else` doesn't fire - try to echo it in the first `if` when you know there is no result

Comment: @J A, PHP offers an alternative syntax for some of its control structures; namely, if, while, for, foreach, and switch. In each case, the basic form of the alternate syntax is to change the opening brace to a colon (:) and the closing brace to endif;, endwhile;, endfor;, endforeach;, or endswitch;, respectively. [Read Here!](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)

Comment: @Zuul: Wow, Did not know about this feature in php.. Point taken. Thanks.

Comment: @ZoltanToth I have echoed it with no results and still don't get the else message. Any other thoughts on why the else might not be working?

Comment: http://us.php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=endforeach&lang=en&scope=404quickref

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You a testing if $bookmark exists! I assume that it always exists, either empty or with array of values!

**Try this:**

```
<?php 

if (is_array($bookmark) && count($bookmark)>=1): 
  foreach($bookmark as $b): ?>               

  <?php if ($b->bookmark_id != 0) { ?>               

    <li><?php echo $bk->bookmark_name; ?></li>

  <?php } ?>


  <?php
  endforeach;
else:
  print "Your bookmark list is empty.";
endif;

?>
```

Read: PHP [is_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php)  |  [count()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)

## EDITED

**Related to the recently posted comment** *"Yes, the array is returning results; I am using the second if statement to limit what is shown. It sounds like my else statement should be tied to the second if clause, instead of the first. The issue for me isn't whether there are results; it's whether after the results are filtered anything remains."*:

```
<?php 

// reset variable
$count = 0;

// if it is an array and is not empty
if (is_array($bookmark) && count($bookmark)>=1): 
  foreach($bookmark as $b):
    if ($b->bookmark_id != 0) {               
      echo '<li>' . $bk->bookmark_name . '</li>';
    } else {
      $count++; // no data, increase
    }

    // check if the counter was increased 
    if ($count>=1) {
      print "Your bookmark list is empty.";
    }
  endforeach;
else:
  print "bookmark not found.";
endif;

?>
```

Comment: No, he's testing if ``$bookmark`` evaluates to true. It could be set to ``false``, ``0``, ``""``, ``array()``, etc., and still execute the ``else`` block. If ``$bookmark`` is an object, as I suspect, your code will actually output nothing, as ``is_array(new ArrayObject)`` returns false.

Comment: Edited a minute ago to add the count() ;)

Comment: Thanks. Am going to test this out now and will get back shortly.

Comment: Tried this out and it's still not triggering the else clause.

Comment: Please perform a `var_dump($bookmark);` before the `if` clause and place that output on the question!

Comment: Okay, the var_dump is in the question

Comment: $bookmark is a valid array and contains data to be processed! It will not trigger the if statement! Are you sure that is that particular else that should be triggering? Or you think that no data was returned and in fact the data is there?

Comment: Yes, the array is returning results; I am using the second if statement to limit what is shown. It sounds like my else statement should be tied to the second if clause, instead of the first. The issue for me isn't whether there are results; it's whether after the results are filtered anything remains.

Comment: Figured it out; I changed my query to avoid any application in the logic and it works fine. I'm accepting and upvoting your answer. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @Zuul Thank you for your edited answer; the truth is, I needed to get the query right and skip the extra application logic. Once I updated it, the else clause worked fine.

Comment: OK, was just to leave the solution to your previous comment! Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 0):

For one reason or another, `$bookmark` is evaluating to true. Since empty strings and arrays already evaluate to false in PHP, we might reasonably suppose that `$bookmark` is in fact an object. Since we can iterate over it with `foreach`, it is probably an instance of [ArrayObject](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php), or a class that extends it. We could debug the exact type of `$bookmark` by writing:

`var_dump($bookmark);`

Since an empty object instance evaluates to true in a PHP conditional, we need to be more specific about what we're checking for.

`if(count($bookmark) > 0):`

This should trigger the else condition properly. As a side note, you should really indent your code properly. :)

Comment: Thanks for this; will test it out shortly. I do indent code properly; it never seems to paste correctly when I copy it onto SO. :S

Comment: Apparently ``empty()`` doesn't actually work on an empty ``ArrayObject`` – edited to use the more reliable ``count()``.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I tested out the count function, and the else condition still isn't showing. Sidenote: earlier I had misspelled a variable and got an error; the else clause showed under the error.

Comment: Okay, the var_dump is in the question

Answer (score 0):

```
if (is_array($bookmark) && !empty($bookmark)) { 
  foreach ($bookmark as $item) {               
   ...
  }
} else {
  echo "Your bookmark list is empty.";
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. You should explain the issue with the OP's code.